# Finding the point that a normal line goes through

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

I have been stumped on a homework problem for quite some time and I'm hoping to get some help with it.

> The line from the origin to the point
>   $(a, f(a))$ on the graph of $f(x) = \frac1{x^2}$
>   is perpendicular to the tangent line to that
>   graph. What is $a$?

I also need to do the exact same problem for $f(x) = 4/x$.

I don't want the answers without knowing how to actually solve the problem. I know that the derivative of $f(x)$ is equal to $-2/x^3$.

Where do I go from here? We do not have a calculus book here at our university and instead get to use "notes" made by a professor here, which happen to not have any examples at all, nor a way to check the results.

The help is much appreciated! If there's any more info I can give, please let me know.

Comment: Solve $f'(a) = -a/f(a)$.  (Slope of tangent is negative reciprocal of radial line from origin.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for the tip. How do I solve for a and f(a) here? I can get them in terms of x and f(x), but then I don't know how to get actual values.

a = -(f'(a) / f(a))  and then  
f(a) = -(a / f'(a))

Comment: @RickyMutschleckner You don't have to solve for $f$.  It is given.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition that the lines be perpendicular is equivalent to the condition that the slope of the tangent be equal to the negative reciprocal of the slope of the radial line from the origin.  The slope of the tangent is $f'(a)$ and the slope of the radial line is $f(a)/a$.  Thus the general problem comes down to solving the equation
$$f'(a) = - a \,\big/\, f(a)\,.$$

Since $f(x)=1/x^2$ is given in the OP's first problem, we have $f(a) = 1/a^2$ and $f'(a) = -2/a^3$. Treating $a$ as an unknown, the equation becomes
$${-2 \over a^3} = -{a \over 1/a^2}\,,$$
which has solutions $a = \pm 2^{1/6}$.

For the second problem, setting $f(a) = 4/a$ etc. leads to $a = \pm 2$.

Comment: I've chosen your answer as the new best answer, as you actually did answer my entire question including providing an example. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner Thanks for the accept.  I wish you the best with the rest of the course.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Let the tangent line have slope $m_1$ and the normal line have slope $m_2$. Then for them to be perpendicular $m_1 \cdot m_2 = -1$.

Comment: Thanks! This is basically what I did. I really appreciate it.